# How can I increase my FTP upload speed on a single instance when in multiple FTP instances I'm fast

Tags: ftp, speed, upload

Here is my problem I have 20 Megabit/s upload speed confirmed on speedtest.net, and when I use my ftp on several settings I can only upload at 450 kilobytes /s or 3.6 Mbits,/s I get around that limitation by opening several instances of FTP program and each instance uploads at 3.6 mbits but I dont like to do that, what hack can I use to use up all of my upload speed that is 20Mbits on a single FTP instance

I have Flash FTP, Filezilla 
cute FTP that is even worst I can upload only at 70 KB/s

Comment: Your connection will operate at the lowest common denominator of all the individual links between you and your destination host. Just because you have a 20 Mbps connection to your ISP doesn't mean you'll get that speed to every host on the Internet.

Comment: What is your latency like to the FTP servers? It sounds like your ISP is oversubscribing the link.

Comment: What hardware are you running this on?

Comment: I have windows 7 and there has to be a hack to get one instance to uplaod at 20 MB when I have to open 6 FTP instances to get the 20mb at 3.mb each one